# Configurar DoctrineExtensions en symfony 2.8 de forma manual

Tags: symfony2, doctrine2

Necesito ayuda para configurar `DoctrineExtensions` (`Gedmo`) de forma manual en `Symfony 2.8 Standard`. Mi acceso a internet es muy limitado y no puedo hacer uso de composer.

Tengo en mi poder las versiones de `DoctrineExtensions 2.3` y `2.4.12`. He intentado seguir el `symfony2.md` que trae el paquete pero no doy con la solución.

Solamente deseo activar la extensión `Tree` para manejar una estructura jerárquica de datos.

Me da errores que me indican que no se ha cargado la clase `TreeListener`, o que no se reconocen las anotaciones `Gedmo` en la entidad para la que deseo crear el arbol.

En caso de que se pueda configuar el `StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle` de forma manual también teniendo descargado el paquete así coma la librería `DoctrineExtensions`, cómo se puede hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolví registrando la librería en el `app/autoload.php`:

```
$loader->add('Gedmo', __DIR__.'/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/');
```

y configurando en `app/config/config.yml` como explica la ayuda para `symfony2` que incluye el paquete